# Maven assembly plugin - complex zipping script

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have next directory structure:

```
    src/main/resources/export/v1/android/
    src/main/resources/export/v1/ios/
    src/main/resources/export/v2/android/
    src/main/resources/export/v2/ios/
    ...
    src/main/resources/export/vn/android/
    src/main/resources/export/vn/ios/
```

And I need to obtain next result:

```
    WEB-INF/export/v1/android.zip
    WEB-INF/export/v1/ios.zip
    WEB-INF/export/v2/android.zip
    WEB-INF/export/v2/ios.zip
    ...
    WEB-INF/export/vn/android.zip
    WEB-INF/export/vn/ios.zip
```

Can I solve the problem with maven-assembly-plugin? If not, is there an another plugin that can cope with it or is it better to write custom class and call it with exec-maven-plugin?

Comment: Yes, you can solve the problem with assembly plugin.

Comment: Maybe I haven't fully expressed my problem - I want to have ability to add new versions of resources (android, ios) with no need to add new assembly file of edit pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with writing java class and runnign it with **exec-maven-plugin** as below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>Running custom java class</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>mycompany.CustomJavaClass</mainClass>
            <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
            <arguments>
                <argument>
                  ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/export
                </argument>
                <argument>
                  ${project.basedir}/target/art-1.0/WEB-INF/export
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've figured out by tinkering with the plugin.  I've been able to create one zip with some arbitrary files in it.  Here's the plugin I've defined:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/resources/my-assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly-id</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And heres my-assembly.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>zip-example</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/java/com/sandbox</directory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

</assembly>
```

I'm *hoping* there's an easier way to do this for your needs, but from this point you can create an assembly file for each zip you need to build and this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but it won't solve my problem. I've already managed to create one zip with one assembly file, but my goal is to have ability to add new versions without bothering with adding new assemblies or editing pom.xml

Comment: @polarfish ok, that might be possible but you're being kind of vague.  Can you be more specific about what will occur in the future?  Is it ok to edit the assembly file?